# React PNPJs sendemail CC and BCC not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sendmail, spfx, pnp-js

I have a SharePoint SPFx react web application. I'm using the following link to send emails on actions: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/sp-utilities-utility/

My current code looks like this:

```
import { default as pnp, sp, ItemAddResult } from "sp-pnp-js";

export interface EmailProperties { 

    To: string[];
    CC: string[];
    BCC?: string[];
    Subject: string;
    Body: string;
    From?: string;
}
```

On button submit I stripped out most of my code but I have this snippet here:

```
async submitNewForm():Promise<any> {
    
    try {       

        //More code here

        const emailProps: EmailProperties = {
            To: ["emailhere@gmail.com"],
            CC: ["cchere@gmail.com"],
            Subject: "Title Here",
            Body: `body code here`
        };

        sp.utility.sendEmail(emailProps).then(_ => {
            console.log("Email Sent to user!");
        });             
    
        
    } catch(error) {

    }
    

}
```

Whenever this action get's triggered, the `To` works but the `CC` and `BCC` do not. I figured maybe that email address I was using was maybe blocking the email from coming. However when I put the BCC email address in the To it works. In my console I don't get any errors I get the "Email Sent to User!"

Any idea on why the CC or BCC is not working, or how I can debug this to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

No errors show up because you don't handle it in the catch block. I suggest adding at least a printing there to find out what's the error and go from there.

Comment: Sorry for the beginner question, but where exactly would I add this print?